# unable to parse users query results using titanium cloud

Tags: javascript, titanium

I am performing a query on users(titanium cloud service) as such:

```
Cloud.Users.query({
  page: 1,
  per_page: 5,
  where: {
    email: 'example@example.com'
  }
}, function(e) {
  if (e.success) {
    alert(JSON.parse(e.users));
  } else if (e.error) {
    alert(e.message);
  } else {}
});
```

After executing the query I am unable to parse `e.users` on `success`, `alert` returns nothing. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to parse e.users which is an array. You should traverse through the array using  a loop and you can simply alert each user using `JSON.stringify` method

Try the following code

```
    Cloud.Users.query({
        page: 1,
        per_page: 5,
        where: {
           email: 'example@example.com'
        }
    }, function (e) {
        if (e.success) {
            alert('Total Users: ' + e.users.length);
            for (var i = 0; i < e.users.length; i++) {
                var user = e.users[i];
                alert(JSON.stringify(user)); //This line will display the details of the user as a string
             }
        } else {
            alert('Error:\n' +
                ((e.error && e.message) || JSON.stringify(e)));
        }
    });
```

You should read [Titanium.Cloud.Users module](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Cloud.Users). Documentation itself shows how to query users.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand from [this example in Titanium docs](http://docs.appcelerator.com/cloud/latest/#!/api/Users-method-query), `e.users` is an array, not a JSON string. You should be able to do something like:

```
for (var i = 0; i < e.users.length; i++) {
    var user = e.users[i];
    alert('id: ' + user.id + '\n' +
        'first name: ' + user.first_name + '\n' +
        'last name: ' + user.last_name);
 }
```